# How should we figure out the missing verb in sentences with modal verbs?

Tags: verb, modal-verb

I have been faced with the following [sentence](https://support-valorant.riotgames.com/hc/de/articles/360046160933-What-is-Vanguard-):

> Riot Vanguard ist die hauseigene Spielsicherheitssoftware von Riot Games, die bei all unseren Spielangeboten das höchste Maß an kompetitiver Integrität sicherstellen soll.

> English Website: Riot Vanguard is Riot Games’ custom game security software, designed to uphold the highest levels of competitive integrity for our offerings.

> Google Translate: Riot Vanguard is Riot Games' proprietary gaming security software designed to ensure the highest level of competitive integrity across all of our gaming offerings.

While I was translating, I found it somewhat weird like it is missing a verb therefore I decided to check the whole sentence in google translate, and the word "design" was in the translation. Then I figured that in the German language, second verbs can be omitted when we are using modal verbs, but how should I find the desired verb of speakers or writers. I found this [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30874/when-can-the-second-verb-be-omitted-when-there-is-a-modal-verb) but the examples were not complicated as the sentence and could not solve my confusion. Is omitting the second verb grammatically correct?

Thank you so much for reading my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no missing verb in the relative clause. The finite verb is "soll", and the infinite verb is "sicherstellen" (to ensure).

A more literal translation is:

> Riot Vanguard is Riot Games' proprietary gaming security software which is  supposed to ensure the highest level of competitive integrity across all of our gaming offerings.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  I saw it in both google translate and also in the English version of the website, so it somehow assured me that the word "design" is necessary. Especially, you do not expect google translate to be so creative in the translation of sentences. So based on your answer it was just the art of translation.